# How to typeset numbers in scientific notation without using a dedicated package such as siunitx?

Tags: formatting

My thesis includes numbers such as, `9.368e-03`, OR `9.368E-03`, spread throughout the main text. I would like to typeset them in the form of a scientific notation such as - `9.683 x 10^-3`.

However, since I am using *TeX Live 2009* on an equally ancient machine and since my thesis document has grown considerably large, I do not want to burden the system by using any of the dedicated packages (e.g. `siunitx`), just to typeset a few numbers properly.

**Is there a simpler way by which I can typeset my numbers in the desired format without using a dedicated scientific notation package?**

Comment: Does you editor have "change all"?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I can't understand your question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Amar Using a suitable search set up (probably a regular expression), you could use your editor to simply change the source from `9.368e-03` to `$9.368\times10^{-3}$`, which would do the job. In any case you will need to search your text for the numbers to add in whatever mark-up you decide to go with.

Comment: @JosephWright Ahh! I am aware of replacing the main input text itself in the manner you suggest. However, I'd rather maintain my input text as it is and simply print out the desired result in PDF using some form of TeX trickery! :) In my experience, it's better to keep your data unchanged, as it allows me to perform quick editing operations, if need be. e.g., to replace some data from the input text, a quick copy/cut/paste between the data file & the input text is sufficient; since, TeX commands will take care of the typesetting using the input format. Hope that explains it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on `xstring` package's `\StrSubstitute` command. It substitutes every occurrence of **`X`** from the selected string element by **`Y`**. A new command is defined, which uses `\StrSubstitute` to remove the `e` OR `E` from the input number (`9.368e-03` or `9.368E-03`) and typesets it in the form of a scientific notation, i.e. `1.536×10^-01`. Rest is self-explanatory.

***Note 1:*** *If the user forgets to write* `e` *or* `E` *in the input, this method will still work!*
***Note 2:*** *For numbers that include* `E` *instead of* `e`*, the user must use the* `\sciE` *method from the solution. The first method, i.e.* `\sci` *will fail in this particular case!*
***Disclaimer:*** This is just one of the many ways in which one can typeset numbers into scientific notation. Also, this solution is based on the assumption that some manual labour is acceptable!

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring} % for text replacement
\usepackage{xcolor}
\providecommand{\sci}[1]{\protect\ensuremath{\times 10^{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{e}{}}}}
% ---- for numbers in format: 9.368e-03 (i.e., numbers using e)
% \sci will remove "e" from the input and typeset the result as:- \times 10^
% \StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{e}{} from the command substitutes "e" by nothing i.e. null!
% usage: if 1.536e-01 is to be converted then -- 1.536\sci{e-01} gives 1.536×10^-01

\providecommand{\sciE}[1]{\protect\ensuremath{\times 10^{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{E}{}}}}
% ---- for numbers in format: 9.368E-03 (i.e., numbers using E)

\begin{document}
{\noindent\Large 1.536e-01 is the input number, which we would like to\\[8pt]
convert to a number in scientific notation, like so \textemdash}\\[0.35in]
%
\hspace*{\fill}{\huge \fcolorbox{cyan!25}{cyan!15}{1.536\sci{e-01}}}\hspace*{\fill}
\vspace*{0.3in}
{                                   % Begin group -- To keep the effect local!
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{table}[h]
\large
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{\hskip 3em}c@{\hskip 6em}c@{\hskip 3em}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{qValue} & \textbf{qValueRes}\\
\midrule
9.368\sci{e-03} & 2.180\sci{e-02} \\
1.058\sci{e-06} & 1.411\sci{e-03} \\
2.563\sci{e-02} & 5.281\sci{e-02} \\
\colorbox{gray!50}{1.536e-01} & \colorbox{gray!50}{1.536e-01} \\ % original numbers!
\colorbox{gray!50}{1.536e-01} & \colorbox{gray!50}{1.536e-01} \\ % original numbers!
1.536\sci{e-01} & 1.536\sci{e-01} \\
2.563\sci{e-02} & 5.281\sci{e-02} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Test}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
}                                   % End group -- To keep the effect local!
\end{document}
```

**MWE Output :**

[image: Output of the code given above:]

Comment: Having the mantissa outside the macro is not great as it doesn't allow for extra features such as writing 1e-5 as 10^{05} without 1 \times and makes the macro more difficult to use in scripts automatically populating the table. I'd like to write `printf("\\mysci(%.3e)" &myfloat)`. I'll stick with `printf(mysci(3, myfloat))`.

Answer (score 8):

For the simple format given, a short chain of dedicated commands can pick up the number. I'm assuming here that the numbers will never have too many digits for TeX's `\number` primitive, which I'm using to trim off any leading zeros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\num}[1]{%
 \ensuremath{%
   \num@auxi#1ee\stop
  }%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxi{}
\def\num@auxi#1e#2e#3\stop{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\num@auxii
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxv
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxii[2]{%
  \num@auxiii#1EE\stop
}
\newcommand*\num@auxiii{}
\def\num@auxiii#1E#2E#3\stop{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\num@auxiv
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxv
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxiv[2]{%
  \number #1 
}
\newcommand*\num@auxv[2]{%
  \number #1 \times 10^{\number #2 }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\num{9.386e-03}
\num{9.386E-03}
\num{9.386}
$\num{9.386e-03}$
\end{document}
```

If you want to retain leading zeros and any leading `+` symbols the code can be slightly simplified

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\num}[1]{%
 \ensuremath{%
   \num@auxi#1ee\stop
  }%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxi{}
\def\num@auxi#1e#2e#3\stop{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\num@auxii
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxiv
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxii[2]{%
  \num@auxiii#1EE\stop
}
\newcommand*\num@auxiii{}
\def\num@auxiii#1E#2E#3\stop{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxiv
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\num@auxiv[2]{%
  #1 \times 10^{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\num{9.386e-03}
\num{9.386E-03}
\num{9.386}
$\num{9.386e-03}$
\end{document}
```

More complex parsing is possible without using `siunitx`, and indeed the [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) package offers quite a bit of this in a package that has been available for many years.

---

How does the above code work? The outer macro

```
\newcommand*{\num}[1]{%
 \ensuremath{%
   \num@auxi#1ee\stop
  }%
}
```

simply grabs the entire input, and inserts it after the first internal macro `\num@auxi`. The latter is going to look for a `e`, so we make sure there will be one to find by including `ee` after the input. (I'll come back to why two `e` tokens later.)

Macro `\num@auxi` comes next

```
\def\num@auxi#1e#2e#3\stop{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \expandafter\num@auxii
  \else
    \expandafter\num@auxv
  \fi
   {#1}{#2}%
}
```

Here we have a *delimited* macro. Everything up to the first `e` will be grabbed as `#1`, everything between that and the second `e` as `#3` and the remainder up to `\stop` as `#3`. There are two outcomes. If the original input contains an `e` then `#1` will be the mantissa, `#2` will be the exponent and `#3` is junk. On the other hand, if there was no `e` then `#1` is the entire number and `#2` is empty. We test for that using `\ifx\relax#2\relax` (true if `#2` is empty) and branch accordingly.

If `e` was not found, there is a bit of set up to do the same again but looking for an `E`. Once that search is done, we have two outcomes: a number with no exponent or a number with exponent. The first case is handled by

```
\newcommand*\num@auxiv[2]{%
  \number #1 
}
```

Due to the way I've set up the code, this receives two arguments, the mantissa and the exponent. We know the latter is empty (it's only there to act as a 'throw away') so we just insert `#1` (the mantissa). I've included `\number` before it, which means TeX will 'tidy up' the input, removing any leading zeros or `+` signs.

If there is an exponent then the code

```
\newcommand*\num@auxv[2]{%
  \number #1 \times 10^{\number #2 }%
}
```

is used: this inserts the mantissa then the exponent with correct formatting. I could have combined the last two macros and included a test on `#2` there, but I felt it was clearer with separate paths.

---

You might wonder in the above why we have

```
\def\num@auxi#1e#2e#3\stop{%
```

rather than just using one `e` (as the input can only have one). It all comes down to making the tests as short as possible. With a definition

```
\def\num@auxi#1e#2\stop{%
```

you might think we'll be OK. However, there's a problem. If I do

```
\num@auxi#1\stop
```

and there is no `e` in the input then TeX will complain as the parameters for `\num@auxi` will not match properly. So instead we need to do

```
\num@auxi#1e\stop
```

to make sure that there is always an `e` to find. However, if the input also contains an `e` then `\num@auxi` ends up splitting so that `#1` is the mantissa but `#2` is the exponent plus that trailing `e`. We could allow for that will a clean-up step, but it's easier to use two `e` tokens and use definition

```
\def\num@auxi#1e#2e#3\stop{%
```

used as

```
\num@auxi#1ee\stop
```

In this case, if there is no `e` in the input we get `#1` as the mantissa, while `#2` and `#3` are empty. On the other hand, if there was an `e` in the input then `#1` is the mantissa, `#2` is the exponent and `#3` mops up the stray `e` (we always discard `#3`). So working this way we need only the one macro to do the work.

Comment: Parsing a known, fixed, format can always be done quite quickly: packages such as `siunitx` or `numprint` come in when you want to deal with multiple formats or where you don't want to worry about the complexities of writing your own parser. For example, life gets a bit more tricky if you want to retain a leading `+` but drop any leading `0`, or want to remove trailing `0`, or ...

Comment: Thank you for your solution and some extensive code for parsing. However, for no fault of yours, I don't really understand what's happening in the solution you've provided. All I see are some `TeX` control sequences interspersed between bunch of conditional statements that somehow re-define the `TeX`'s `\number` primitive. How exactly, I have no clue about that! :|

Comment: @Amar No, I would never redefine `\number`! I'll add some comments in a bit.

Comment: Wow! Impressive! A very clear explanation. Thank you! .. Just one more question :) .. Why two `e`/ `E`'s? The input number will always have one `e`/ `E` representing the beginning of the exponent. Is it a parsing requirement?

Comment: @Amar See update: it's a bit too complex for a comment. (It's also a general trick: might make a good generic question if we don't already have it.)

Comment: Thanks for the latest update! I (kind of) get it now! :) I shall try to post a generic question regarding the same.