# Easiest Latex software

Tags: editors, learning, wysiwyg

I am doing summer project in maths and I have to type my report. I am good with the latex I write on mathstack that I have learned through experience but when it comes to softwares, I do not know anything like those commands `\begin` `\end` does not make sense to me.

Is there any software which can automatically put these commands in, so that in b/w we can type whatever stuff we want?

Also if not, at least you guys can tell me if there is any latex software which shows the output on half of screen(right half), as I type on left half and compile, (I saw it somewhere).

Anyways, I have to download a software and will have to go through some you tube videos, so please suggest me relatively easy Latex software.

Thanks!

**P.S.** Please edit the tags as you wish, I did not understand many tags here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to look into [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/), which is a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor for LaTeX.

Comment: TeXmacs has recently seen a swell of popularity and LyX is a common recommendation, but neither of these really suit *my* fancy.

Comment: You may also find this blog post helpful: http://www.seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html – also, as a newcomer to TeX, I would value your input of topics for future blog posts and videos. As you get more experience with (La)TeX, it gets harder to remember what the important questions are for new folks like you.

Comment: I have Texnic Centre in my PC, I have no idea where to begin..

Comment: (I *seriously* recommend that blog post. Knowing the lingo will help you understand what's going on around you *and* will help you ask more specific questions.)

Comment: I would consider Overleaf (www.overleaf.com) if you are starting to learn LaTeX. It does not require any installation, and has a split interface showing both source and output. You don't even need to register.

Comment: perhaps texstudio? `texstudio.sourceforge.net/`

Comment: My suggestion would be to work from a template; that is, learn by example. Regardless, this is really a poor question in my opinion. Start with [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764).

Comment: @onewhaleid Thanx, overleaf works fine for me

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Jon Warbrick's [Essential LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-essential) and David Carlisle's [Essential Mathematical LaTeX](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~smsulli2/MA724_Spring2014/el2emath.pdf) for a starter. And you don't need to install anything on your computer: use either [sharelatex](http://www.sharelatex.com) or [overleaf](http://www.overleaf.com) on your browser, if you have access to a reliable internet connection. They provide access to a full LaTeX installation, a LaTeX editor with autocompletion, and a pdf viewer.